# Unordered combinations and generating related index-vectors in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data with three individuals `A`, `B`, and `C`, and each of them has two status (`1` and `2`). The combinations are: `A`, `B`, `C`, `AB`, `AC`, `BC`, and `ABC`(i.e., 2^2-1 combinations). Therefore, I need index-like vectors to refer to each combination. For instance, the index-vector for combination `A` will be `IV<-c(1, 2, 2)`. For the other example, the index-vector for combination `AB` will be `IV<-c(1, 1, 2)`. Finally, the index-vector for combination `ABC` will be `IV<-c(1, 1, 1)`.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expand.grid` :

```
IV<-expand.grid(2:1,2:1,2:1)[-1,]
rownames(IV)<-c('A','B','AB','C','AC','BC','ABC'); colnames(IV)<-NULL
IV<-as.matrix(IV)

    IV
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
A      1    2    2
B      2    1    2
AB     1    1    2
C      2    2    1
AC     1    2    1
BC     2    1    1
ABC    1    1    1
```

To use a vector put the name in quotes and don't forget the comma :

```
IV['A',]
[1] 1 2 2
```

Note that if you want to do the same with four (or more) letters, you could do :

```
number<-4
IV<-expand.grid(replicate(number,2:1,simplify=FALSE))[-1,]; colnames(IV)<-LETTERS[1:number]
IV<-as.matrix(IV)

# this will computes the rownames
for (i in 1:nrow(IV)){
    temp<-''
    for (j in 1:ncol(IV)){
        if (all.equal(IV[i,j],1)==TRUE) {
            temp<-paste0(temp,colnames(IV)[j])
        }
    } 
    rownames(IV)[i]<-temp
}
colnames(IV)<-NULL
```

For the order, use

```
IV<-IV[order(row.names(IV)),]
IV<-IV[order(sapply(1:nrow(IV),function(x){nchar(row.names(IV)[x])})),]
```

which could be shortened in

```
IV[order(sapply(1:nrow(IV),function(x){nchar(row.names(IV)[x])}),row.names(IV)),]
```

this will order by the alphabetical order first, then by the length so that it gives :

```
rownames(IV)
 [1] "A"    "B"    "C"    "D"    "AB"   "AC"   "AD"   "BC"   "BD"   "CD"   "ABC"  "ABD"  "ACD"  "BCD" 
[15] "ABCD"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eitnne. I wonder if there is any way I can reorder the combinations as `A`, `B`, `C`, `AB`, `AC`, `BC`, `ABC`?

Comment: Got it, thanks. One more question if it is okay. Do you mind to explain this code a little bit to me? `IV[order(sapply(1:nrow(IV),function(x){nchar(row.names(IV)[x])}),row.names(IV))‌​,]` To me, it seems like it orders the `sapply` part first, and then orders `row.names(IV)` part. Is that how the code order works? Thanks! @eitnne

Comment: @tzu: the code is in two parts : first, it takes the number of character `nchar` of each row name and orders `IV` by those length (length 1 then 2 ...), second, it orders those groups by alphabetical order. You were right in your comment as the first order (`nchar`) has the priority over the second.

Comment: Thank you so much! @etienne